# Regularity solution of the Poisson equation with mixed boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Following Grisvard, if $\Omega$ is an open, bounded and convex domain, and $f\in L^2$, there exist a unique $u\in H^2$ solution of 
$$
\left \{
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta u&=f\; \textrm{in } \Omega, \\
u&=0\; \textrm{in } \partial \Omega.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Now, I would like to know if there is a similar result for the following problem 
$$
\left \{
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta u&=f\; \textrm{in } \Omega, \\
u&=0\; \textrm{on }  \Gamma, \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}&=0\; \textrm{on } \partial \Omega \setminus\Gamma,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

where $\Gamma$ is an non-empty subset of $\partial \Omega$. I know that with Lax-Milgram theorem, one can easily get the $H^1$ regularity. But, is it possible to have an $H^2$ regularity as in the previous case ?

Thanks in advance for the answer.